# Genitive Case after transitive verb?

Tags: відмінювання, керування-відмінками, accusative-case, facultative-animacy

My textbook had the following example:

> Сестра написaла **цього листа**

Note the use of genitive case after написала. I asked a native speaker and they said that it sounded correct to them, but that the following variant was also possible to say:

> Сестра написaла **цей лист**

I am at a loss for why цього листа is used in the genitive case in the first example. What is the relevant grammar used here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> <sup>[Книга](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AF%D0%BA_%D0%BC%D0%B8_%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE) [„Як ми говоримо“](http://yak-my-hovorymo.wikidot.com/rodovyj-chy-znahidnyj-vidminok-dodatka) [(Борис Антоненко-Давидович)](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D0%94%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87_%D0%91%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81_%D0%94%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87)</sup>
>   **[Родовий](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BA#.D0.97.D0.BD.D0.B0.D1.87.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.BD.D1.8F) чи [знахідний](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%85%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BA#.D0.A1.D1.83.D1.87.D0.B0.D1.81.D0.BD.D1.96.D1.81.D1.82.D1.8C) відмінок [додатка](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA_(%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE))?**
>
> Як буде правильно сказати: писати (читати) *листа* чи *лист*, пришити *ґудзик* чи *ґудзика*? Такі питання часто виникають перед тими, хто негаразд відчуває дух української мови. Як на те, трапляються інколи випадки, коли той самий іменник, виконуючи в реченнях синтаксичну функцію додатка, в одному реченні стоїть у родовому відмінку, а в другому — в знахідному, наприклад: «Послухали *доброї поради* високошановного народолюбця» [(Борис Грінченко)](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D1%80%D1%96%D0%BD%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%BE_%D0%91%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81_%D0%94%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87) і «Він *дасть пораду*, як і що, — знайшов вихід Антін» [(Степан Чорнобривець)](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%86%D1%8C_%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BD_%D0%90%D0%BD%D1%96%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87). То від чого залежить той чи той відмінок додатка? Чи є якесь правило щодо цього?
>
> У розділі [«Дієслова»](http://yak-my-hovorymo.wikidot.com/diyeslova) ми побачимо далі, що є дієслова, які керують іменниками тільки в якомусь певному відмінку, а тим часом обмежимося лиш зауваженням, що, на відміну від російської мови, в українській мові іменник-додаток часто стоїть у родовому, а не в знахідному відмінку: «Бабуся пильнує *малої*» [(Марко Вовчок)](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%BE_%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%87%D0%BE%D0%BA); «Де шукати *благостині*» [(Пантелеймон Куліш)](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%96%D1%88_%D0%9F%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%9E%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87); «Гляди, дядьку, *порядку*» [(Матвій Номис)](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B9_%D0%9D%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%81); «Заспівай мені, доню, *тієї Вкраїни*» [(Григорій Косинка)](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%93%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%96%D0%B9_%D0%9C%D0%B8%D1%85%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87).
>
> Отож, у першій фразі ліпше сказати: писати (читати) *листа*; та й у другій теж ближче буде до народнорозмовної української традиції: пришити *ґудзика*, купити *хліба* тощо.

---

> <sup>Book [”How do we speak“](http://yak-my-hovorymo.wikidot.com/rodovyj-chy-znahidnyj-vidminok-dodatka) [(Borys Antonenko-Davydovyč)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borys_Antonenko-Davydovych)</sup>
>   **[Genitive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genitive_case#Slavic_languages) or [Accusative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accusative_case) [Object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_(grammar))?**
>
> How to say correctly: писати (читати) *листа* or *лист*, пришити *ґудзик* or *ґудзика*? Such questions often arise before those who do not feel the spirit of the Ukrainian language. As for the occasional cases, when the same noun, performing in sentences the syntactic function of the application, in one sentence is in the Genitive case, and in the second one in the Accusative, for example: ”Послухали *доброї поради* високошановного народолюбця“ [(Borys Hrinčenko)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borys_Hrinchenko) and ”Він дасть *пораду*, як і що, — знайшов вихід Антін“ (Stepan Čornobryvecj). So which depends on the application’s case? Is there any rule about this?
>
> In the [”Verbs“](http://yak-my-hovorymo.wikidot.com/diyeslova) section, we will see further that there are verbs that govern nouns only in some particular case, and meanwhile we confine ourselves to the remark that, unlike the Russian language, the noun-application in the Ukrainian language is often in the Genitive, not in the Accusative case: ”Бабуся пильнує *малої*“ [(Marco Vovčok)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marko_Vovchok); ”Де шукати *благостині*“ [(Pantelejmon Kuliš)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Panteleimon_Kulish); ”Гляди, дядьку, *порядку*“ [(Matvij Nomys)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matviy_Nomys); ”Заспівай мені, доню, *тієї Вкраїни*“ (Hryhorij Kosynka).
>
> So, in the first sentence, it's better to say: писати (читати) листа; and in the second one, too, will be closer to the Ukrainian-speaking folk tradition: пришити *ґудзика*, купити *хліба*, etc.

---

[Borys Rohoza](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B0_%D0%91%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81_%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87) [agrees](http://mova.kreschatic.kiev.ua/274.htm) with above mentioned.

---

---

> <sup>Вікіпедія ¬ [Знахідний відмінок ⇒ Сучасність](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%85%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BA#.D0.A1.D1.83.D1.87.D0.B0.D1.81.D0.BD.D1.96.D1.81.D1.82.D1.8C)</sup>
>   Роль знахідного істотного чоловічого роду [2 відміни](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%B0#.D0.94.D1.80.D1.83.D0.B3.D0.B0), а також множини всіх відмін грає родовий відмінок (*зустріти гостя, любити брата, побачити сестер*). В офіційно-діловому стилі мовлення форма знахідного неістотного чоловічого роду 2 відміни збігається з формою [називного](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BA) (*відкрити рот, написати лист, купити олівець*). У розмовно-побутовому мовленні трапляється вживання родового відмінка у ролі знахідного неістот (*відкрити рота, написати листа, купити олівця*).

---

> <sup>Ukrainian Wikipedia ¬ [Accusative case ⇒ Modern Ukrainian](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%85%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BA#.D0.A1.D1.83.D1.87.D0.B0.D1.81.D0.BD.D1.96.D1.81.D1.82.D1.8C)</sup>
>   The role of Accusative case of animate masculine [2nd declension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ukrainian_grammar#Second_declension) and of plural of all declensions play Genitive case (*зустріти гостя, любити брата, побачити сестер*). In official-business style of speech, Accusative case of inanimate masculine 2nd declension is in [Normative case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominative_case)’s form (*відкрити рот, написати лист, купити олівець*). In spoken language — in Genitive case (*відкрити рота, написати листа, купити олівця*).

Answer (score 6):

By the way, an opinion exists, that usage of certain case depends on the level of specifics meant. "To bring sugar": 
Genitive case: *принести цукру* (small amount / part from the whole / characteristics unimportant), 
Accusative case: *принести цукор* (all of it / specific entity / important and underlined object).

Yu.Beliaiev [gives](http://kulturamovy.univ.kiev.ua/KM/pdfs/Magazine19-16.pdf) (uk) these examples from Ukrainian literature: 
G.c. «Батько *торта не купив*» (М. Зарудний) // "Father didn't buy a cake"
A.c. «Почекай, дівко, не *воруши* увесь *попіл*» (М. Стельмах) // "Wait, girl, don't stir all the ashes"
But he also makes a conclusion that recently Accusative case becomes more used regardless of context.

---

Окрім того, існує думка, що використання того чи того відмінка залежить від рівня конкретики, який мається на увазі: 
Р.в. *принести цукру* (невелику кількість / певну частину від цілого / не важливого якого), 
З.в. *принести цукор* (увесь / конкретну місткість / важливий і підкреслюваний предмет).

Ю. І. Бєляєв [наводить](http://kulturamovy.univ.kiev.ua/KM/pdfs/Magazine19-16.pdf) такі приклади: 
Р.в. «Батько *торта не купив*» (М. Зарудний) 
З.в. «Почекай, дівко, не *воруши* увесь *попіл*» (М. Стельмах)
Однак сам же підводить підсумок, що знахідний відмінок розповсюджується дедалі більше не залежно від контексту.

Comment: *принести цукру* is a remainder of **Partitive case**. It is used in Ukrainian for mass-measurable objects (e.g., sugar, wheat, tea) when referring to an **unidentifiable part of available mass**. The Wikipedia article [mentions Russian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partitive_case#Russian) (does anyone care to edit it?), but this is exactly the case for Ukrainan as well.

Comment: Ну, стаття непогана. Там також згадується вплив російської:
_Цілком очевидною є тенденція до активізації знахідного, особливо в наукових, професійно-технічних текстах та в усному мовленні. Відбувається зрушення усталеної норми. При двомовності спілкування на Україні ця тенденція знаходить підтримку в російській мові._ Щодо частковості також є згадка в [Вікі](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BA#.D0.97.D0.BD.D0.B0.D1.87.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.BD.D1.8F) – останній пункт.

Comment: The whole thing may also look similar to a/the in English but it seems careless to draw serious paralells here.